# Как в контроллере изменить возвращаемый тип на DTO?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Добрый день! 
Необходимо реализовать login/logout как в [данном](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/) примере, но возвращать нужно json ответ вместо редиректа на jsp форму. Знаю что в контроллере возвращаемый тип должен быть DTO вместо строки. Подскажите что необходимо изменить в проекте и как правильно создать DTO для login/logout/registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй над методом контроллера поставить аннотацию @ResponseBody тип возвращаемого объекта изменить на созданный класс dto и соответственно вернуть нужно объект этого типа.

Comment: как создать DTO для login/logout/registration? не могу найти пример

Comment: dto это обычный java class.

public class loginDto {
  private String login;
  private String password;

}

там объявляешь любые поля которые хочешь чтобы сервер тебе вернул в виде json и все. Я бы подсказал конкретнее но не зная задача не могу.